# Automatically "Press Enter to Exit" in bash?

Tags: bash, dos, wine

In a bash script, I'm using wine to call a DOS program that requires me to "Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit". How do I do that automatically and continue with the rest of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo | wine dosprogram.exe

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the [`expect`](http://expect.nist.gov/) program.

Here is an example script:

```
spawn /path/to/program/Dynamips
expect -- "->"
send "start R1\r"
expect -- "->" {
  sleep 5
  send "start R2\r"
}
expect eof
```

You can invoke this with:

```
expect scriptname
```

Answer (score 0):

Send it the input 0x0D