# Automatically press Enter to continue in Bash

Tags: bash, input, enter

I want to change RSA Keys to open ssh connections without any problems. It works fine, if I use [this tutorial](http://www.madmadmod.com/sysadmin/4-ssh-key-exchange-or-how-to-logon-without-entering-a-password.html) but I want to have it done in a bash script. Unfortunately I am asked to enter a passphrase (I want to enter nothing). How can I achieve to automatically press <kbd>Enter</kbd> three times in a row, when the script reaches this point?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349771/automatically-press-enter-to-exit-in-bash) did not help, because I am not allowed to install new programs on my work PC and the `echo | command` trick seems only to work for one <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Also I need to enter "n" and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, if the procedure was already made, to not overwrite any files. How do i achieve that?

Comment: Use `echo -e "\n"` if you need two new lines.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you just need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a bunch of times this will do it:

`yes "" | command`

For anything more complicated than that you might want to use `expect` as suggested in the other thread, which you can install in your homedir without root priviliges.

PS: Please avoid re-posting questions in the future. If you don't like an answer for some reason, just comment on it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to just create ssh keys in a bash script without requiring any user input, you can specify arguments to `ssh-keygen`:

```
# rsa type (default), no passphrase, write to file id_rsa and id_rsa.pub
captain:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f id_rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
fe:4a:82:08:0e:ab:b7:02:62:11:4d:3e:79:a4:d3:98 mrb@captain.local
```